# What is the difference between is_a and instanceof?

Tags: php

I am aware that [`instanceof`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.type.php) is an operator and that [`is_a`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-a.php) is a method.

Is the method slower in performance? What would you prefer to use?

Comment: is_a() could be slower - but you can call it using call_user_func() while instanceof cannot be called this way...

Answer (score 230, accepted):

**Update**

As of [PHP 5.3.9](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-a.php#refsect1-function.is-a-changelog), the functionality of `is_a()` has changed. The original answer below states that `is_a()` *must* accept an `Object` as the first argument, but PHP versions >= 5.3.9 now accept an optional third boolean argument `$allow_string` (defaults to `false`) to allow comparisons of string class names instead:

```
class MyBaseClass {}
class MyExtendingClass extends MyBaseClass {}

// Original behavior, evaluates to false.
is_a(MyExtendingClass::class, MyBaseClass::class);

// New behavior, evaluates to true.
is_a(MyExtendingClass::class, MyBaseClass::class, true);
```

The key difference in the new behavior between `instanceof` and `is_a()` is that `instanceof` will always check that the target is an instantiated object of the specified class (including extending classes), whereas `is_a()` only requires that the object be instantiated when the `$allow_string` argument is set to the default value of `false`.

---

**Original**

Actually, `is_a` is a function, whereas `instanceof` is a language construct.  `is_a` will be significantly slower (since it has all the overhead of executing a function call), but the overall execution time is minimal in either method.

It's no longer deprecated as of 5.3, so there's no worry there.

There is one difference however.  `is_a` being a function takes an object as parameter 1, and a string (variable, constant, or literal) as parameter 2. So:

```
is_a($object, $string); // <- Only way to call it
```

`instanceof` takes an object as parameter 1, and can take a class name (variable), object instance (variable), or class identifier (class name written without quotes) as parameter 2.

```
$object instanceof $string;      // <- string class name
$object instanceof $otherObject; // <- object instance
$object instanceof ClassName;    // <- identifier for the class
```

Comment: Why was `is_a` undeprecated?

Comment: @theodore-r-smith According to the documentation it "has been undeprecated by popular request" http://php.net/manual/en/migration53.undeprecated.php

Comment: instanceof can take either a string as parameter, object, or an identifier (class name written without quotes) @ircmaxell - can you provide an example for string as parameter ?

Comment: @danip `$class = 'Foo'; var_dump($obj instanceof $class);`

Comment: thanks, strange that var_dump($obj instanceof 'Foo') is not working

Comment: @danip: correct, it can't be a constant string (and that would not make sense, since you could just use a literal identifier anyway)...

Comment: One more thing to note about `is_a` vs the `instanceof` operator is that `is_a` will accept expressions for the second parameter, while instanceof wont. For example `is_a($object, 'Prefix_'.$name)` works while `$object instanceof 'Prefix_'.$name` doesn't

Comment: You should add that ``instanceof`` cannot take a string parameter as its first argument. Currently your description makes it sounds like it could.

Comment: For is_a, if you set the third parameter to true, then parameter 1 sent to is_a can optionally be a string. instanceof does not have this flexibility.

Comment: Beware that with `is_a` you have to specify the complete namespace on the 2nd parameter, even if you import the class with `use`.

Comment: @ViniciusPinto unless you use `is_a($foo, Foo::class)`. At which point you don't need to (since you're dynamically creating the string).

Comment: @ircmaxell very nice! this requires php 5.5+ though

Comment: `is_a` never should have been deprecated in the first place. It's a little late to fix it now though. The problem is that the `instanceof` operator throws syntax errors in PHP 4, and since `is_a` was deprecated at the exact same time as the operator was introduced it became impossible to write code for both PHP 4 and 5 without throwing an E_STRICT around. You can't even do `if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, 5) >= 0) { /* use instanceof */ } else { /* use is_a */ }` because it would still cause a syntax error in PHP 4.

Comment: @ircmaxell, In OOP , an object is an instance of a class. So why was `instanceOf` developed to allow to take an object along with class name or class identifier as the second parameter ?

Comment: "is_a will be significantly slower [...] but the overall execution time is minimal in either method." LOL, which one is it? There's this ridiculous conception among many developers that function calls are slow and therefore bad. Meanwhile, rarely does this trope surface for OOP in general where object instantiation is a thousand times more expensive than the minimal overhead of a function call, especially one as trivial as `is_a()`. This is by far the most pervasive example of premature optimization. So premature that avoidance is advised in comments before an iota of code is ever written.

Answer (score 57):

Here is performance results of [**is_a()**](http://php.net/is_a) and [**instanceof**](http://php.net/instanceof):

```
Test name       Repeats         Result          Performance     
instanceof      10000           0.028343 sec    +0.00%
is_a()          10000           0.043927 sec    -54.98%
```

Test source is [here](https://github.com/nafigator/php-bench/blob/master/Tests/IsAVsInstanceOf.php).

Comment: In other words, the difference is only important if you need to save ~0.015 seconds per 10000 uses.

Comment: As of `php 7` there is no difference.

Comment: @CJDennis By experience, when everybody think like this, the final product will be slower than expected. (Soft + OS + servers unoptimized). Remember that time added is not always linear, but can be exponential. Always have perfomance in mind.

Comment: @Toto There is a excellent blog post about what experienced developers can learn from beginners. Hopefully you can see it at the top right. Beware of premature optimisation! Only solve timing problems _after they've become problems_! If the performance is acceptable as it is, don't spend time changing it!

Comment: @CJDennis "Avoid premature optimization" is a good rule when there is a cost to pay in terms of development time. When writing new code, you might as well keep best practices in mind regarding performance, especially when they don't require any extra effort.

Comment: @okdewit How much development time would go into checking the difference? If it's more than 0.015 seconds, it's not worth it.

Comment: If you think that runtime performance difference between `is_a()` and `instanceof` is important, you shouldn't be using PHP in the first place. Use C, C++ or Rust instead. I use `is_a()` when the first parameter is a string and `instanceof` otherwise because I think it's more readable.

Answer (score 9):

`instanceof` can be used with other object instances, the class's name, or an interface. <strike>I don't think that `is_a()` works with interfaces (only a string representing a class name), but correct me if it does.</strike> (Update: See https://gist.github.com/1455148)

Example from [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.type.php):

```
interface MyInterface
{
}

class MyClass implements MyInterface
{
}

$a = new MyClass;
$b = new MyClass;
$c = 'MyClass';
$d = 'NotMyClass';

var_dump($a instanceof $b); // $b is an object of class MyClass
var_dump($a instanceof $c); // $c is a string 'MyClass'
var_dump($a instanceof $d); // $d is a string 'NotMyClass'
```

outputs:

```
bool(true)
bool(true)
bool(false)
```

Comment: `is_a` does work with interfaces the same way as `instanceof` (I was going to say the same thing, but I checked it before submitting, and it does indeed work)...

Comment: -1 please summarize the update rather than just linking to a gist.  That is unhelpful for people trying to learn.

Answer (score 8):

Besides the speed, another important difference is how they handle edge cases.

```
is_a($x1, $x2) // fatal error if x2 is not a string nor an object
$x1 instanceof $x2  // returns false even if $x2 is int, undefined, etc.
```

So, is_a() highlights possible bugs while instanceof suppresses them.

Answer (score 7):

In regards to ChrisF's answer, `is_a()` [is no longer deprecated](http://php.net/is_a) as of PHP 5.3.0. I find it's always safer to go by the official source for things like this.

With regards to your question, Daniel, I can't say about the performance differences, but part of it will come down to readibility and which you find easier to work with.

Also, [there is some discussion](http://us.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.type.php#71562) about the confusion around negating an `instanceof` check vs `is_a()`. For example, for `instanceof` you would do:

```
<?php
if( !($a instanceof A) ) { //... }
?>
```

vs the following for `is_a()`:

```
<?php
if( !is_a($a, 'A' ) { //... }
?>
```

or

```
<?php
if( is_a($a, 'A') === FALSE) { //... }
?>
```

**Edit** Looks like ChrisF deleted his answer, but the first part of my answer still stands.

Answer (score 7):

There is a scenario where only `is_a()` works and `instanceof` will fail.

`instanceof` expects a literal class name or a variable that is either an object or a string (with the name of a class) as its right argument.

But if you want to provide the string of a class name from a function call it will not work and result in a syntax error.

However, the same scenario works fine with `is_a()`.

Example:

```
<?php

function getClassName() : string
{
    return "Foobar";
}

class Foobar
{
    private $xyz;

}

$x = new Foobar();

// this works of course
var_dump($x instanceof Foobar);

// this creates a syntax error
var_dump($x instanceof getClassName());

// this works
var_dump(is_a($x, getClassName()));
```

This is based on PHP 7.2.14.

Answer (score 2):

Here are performance results obtained from [here](http://dev.airve.com/demo/speed_tests/php/is_a_is_object.php):

**`instanceof` is faster.**

**Functions**

```
function method_1($a = null) { 
    return is_object($a) && is_a($a, 'Example');
}

function method_2($a = null) {
    return is_a((object) $a, 'Example');
}

function method_3($a = null) {
    return $a instanceof 'Example';
}
```

**Times (run 5000 times each)**

```
0.00573397 // method_1(5) 
0.01437402 // method_2(5) 
0.00376201 // method_3(5)
```

Answer (score 2):

The optimization is minimal. And micro-optimisations are never a real good answer, in front of the readability, understandability, and stability of the code.

(personally, I prefer `instanceof`, but the choice is yours)

The main difference is the possibility to use a direct class name with `instanceof`

```php
$a instanceof MyClass
```

is shorter than

```php
is_a($a, MyClass::class)
```

(ok… it’s not trivial)

The syntactical coloration between `instanceof` (language structure) and `is_a` is useful too (for me). Letting function color to bigger operations.
And for single use in `if`, `instanceof` doesn’t need more parenthesis.

Note: Of course, instead of `MyClass::class` you can use a shorter direct string:

```php
is_a($a,'MyClass')
```

**But use direct string in a code isn’t a good practice.**

The syntactical coloration is better and more useful if you can make a difference between simple string and class names.

And it's easier to change names with constant class names. Especially if you use a namespace with an alias.

So, why use `is_a()`?

For the same reason: readability and understandability, the choice is yours.

Especially when used with `!` or other boolean operators: `is_a` seems more practical with parenthesis.

```php
if ($a && (!is_a ($a, MyClass::class) || is_a ($a, MyOtherClass::class)))
```

is more readable than:

```
if ($a && (!($a instanceof MyClass) || ($a intanceof MyOtherClass)))
```

Another good reason is when you need to use a callback in functions, like `array_map`...

`instanceof` isn’t a function, it’s a language construct, so you cannot use it as a callback.

In those cases, `is_a` may be useful.

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak for performance -- I haven't measured anything yet -- but depending on what you are attempting, there are limitations with `instanceof`.  Check out my question, just recently, about it:

[PHP 'instanceof' failing with class constant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002594/php-instanceof-failing-with-class-constant)

I've ended up using `is_a` instead.  I like the structure of `instanceof` better (I think it reads nicer) and will continue to use it where I can.

Answer (score 1):

One interesting thing to note about is_a(): If you're using autoloader, namespaces and aliases for your classes, you'll need to use the true and full name of your class on is_a() because the method will not understand quite well what is what on your context. instanceof, on the other hand, understands it.

For instance (no pun intended):

```
<?php
namespace MyNamespace;

use \MyNamespace\User;
use \MyNamespace\Thing as Something;

class Test
{
    public function doTest()
    {
        $user = new User();
        var_dump(is_a($user, "User")); // false
        var_dump(is_a($user, "\MyNamespace\User")); // true
        var_dump($user instanceof User); // true
        var_dump($user instanceof \MyNamespace\User); // true
    }

    public function doAnotherTest()
    {
        $something = new Something();
        var_dump(is_a($something, "Something")); // false
        var_dump(is_a($something, "\MyNamespace\Thing")); // true
        var_dump($something instanceof Thing); // true
        var_dump($something instanceof \MyNamespace\Thing); // true
    }
}
```