# what in PHP is similar to Actionscript 's "is" operator?

Tags: php, actionscript-3

As far I know the **is** operator in ActionScript does the following: (rectify me, if I am wrong)

1. Tests whether a variable or expression is compatible with a given data type.
2. Examines the inheritance hierarchy
3. Can be used to check whether an object is an instance of a particular class or a child (or grandchild, great grandchild, great great grandchild, and so on) of a particular class.
4. Check whether an object is an instance of a class that implements a particular interface

Now I want to know what in **PHP** is/are similar to Actionscript 's "**is**" operator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ActionScript's **is** operator is equivalent to PHP's **instanceof** operator

```
<?php
class Person {}
$p1 = new Person();
$p2 = new Person();
echo ($p1 instanceof $p2)?"True":"False"; //o/p: True bcz both $p1 & $p2 are the instances of same class
echo ($p1 instanceof Person)?"True":"False";//True , checking through class name

interface LoyalCustomer{}
class Customer extends Person implements LoyalCustomer {}
$c1 = new Customer();
echo ($c1 instanceof $p1)?"True":"False";//True

class RegularCustomer extends Customer{}
$rc1 = new RegularCustomer();
echo ($rc1 instanceof $p1)?"True":"False";//True
echo ($rc1 instanceof $c1)?"True":"False";//True
echo ($rc1 instanceof RegularCustomer)?"True":"False";//True
echo ($rc1 instanceof Customer)?"True":"False";//True
echo ($rc1 instanceof Person)?"True":"False";//True

echo ($p1 instanceof LoyalCustomer)?"True":"False";//False
echo ($c1 instanceof LoyalCustomer)?"True":"False";//True
echo ($rc1 instanceof LoyalCustomer)?"True":"False";//True
echo ($p1 instanceof $rc1)?"True":"False";//False
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

In PHP you have construction `instanceof`:

```
$a instanceof MyClass
```

Answer (score 0):

The ["is" operator](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=03_Language_and_Syntax_09.html#122921) is used for comparing/testing data type membership (type checking). In php, you can used [instanceof](http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.opcodes.instanceof.php) to [check the specific type of the object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8091143/how-to-check-for-a-specific-type-of-object-in-php/8091175#8091175).

```
$obj = new A();

if ($obj instanceof A) {
   ...
}
```