# How can I check if a object is an instance of a specific class?

Tags: php, simplexml

Is there a way to check if an object is an `SimpleXMLELement`?

```
private function output_roles($role) {
    foreach ($role as $current_role) {
        $role_ = $current_role->attributes();
        $role_type = (string) $role_->role;
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td><b>" . $role_type . "</b></td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        $roles = $role->xpath('//role[@role="Administrator"]//role[not(role)]');
        if (is_array($roles)) {
            $this->output_roles($roles);
        }
    }
}
```

This is my function and the `$role->xpath` is only possible if the provided object is a `SimpleXMLElement`. Anyone?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Check for a Specific Type of Object in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8091143/how-to-check-for-a-specific-type-of-object-in-php)

Answer (score 103, accepted):

You can check if an object is an instance of a class with [`instanceof`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.type.php), e.g.

```
if($role instanceof SimpleXMLElement) {
    //do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 15):

The following methods and operators are useful to determine whether a particular variable is an object of a specified class:

- **$var instanceof TestClass**: The operator “instanceof” returns true if
  the variable $var is an object of the specified class (here is:
  “TestClass”).
- **get_class($var)**: Returns the name of the class from $var, which can
  be compared with the desired class name.
- **is_object($var)**: Checks whether the variable $var is an object.

Read more in [How to check if an object is an instance of a specific class in PHP?](https://stackhowto.com/how-to-check-if-an-object-is-an-instance-of-a-specific-class-in-php/)