# Magento 1.9 Block Cache - prevent form key caching on Mage Catalog Block Product View

Tags: forms, magento, block, magento-1.6, magento-1.9

Hey Magento Professionals,

I was using Magentos Block Cache mechanism for better performance on product pages.
It worked great on Magento CE 1.6.2 but now I'm upgrading to CE 1.9.0.1 and block caching does not go well with Magentos new form keys.

The product pages are still being cached, but they're naturally cached including the new form key in the forms actions. When another user tries to add products to cart it won't work, because the other users form key was cached.
So no product is being added and the cart stays empty.

Is there a way to kind of inject the form key into the cached code or another way for caching product pages ?

The caching methods in my extended Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View looks like this

```
protected function _construct()
{
        $this->addData(array(
            'cache_tags'        => array(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::CACHE_TAG . "_" . $this->getProduct()->getId()),
        ));
}

public function getCacheKey()
{
    if (!$this->hasData('cache_key')) {
        //$cacheKey = LAYOUTNAME_STORE+ID_PRODUCT+ID
        $cacheKey = $this->getNameInLayout().'_STORE'.Mage::app()->getStore()->getId().'_PRODUCT'.$this->getProduct()->getId();         
        $this->setCacheKey($cacheKey);
    }
    return $this->getData('cache_key');
}

public function getCacheLifetime()
{     
      if($this->getNameInLayout()!='product.info') return null;
      if(!$this->cacheEnabled()) return null;         
      return 9999999999;
}

public static function cacheEnabled() {
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a quickfix for now, but still looking for a better solutions.
For now I added the _afterToHtml($html) method in my extended block and inject the form_key before returning the html from cache.
If someone else needs this quickfix make sure the if condition is right. It makes sure that this is only done in the block I'm really caching and not on other Product View Blocks.

So this is my current quickfix:

```
public function _afterToHtml($html) {
    if($this->getNameInLayout() == 'product.info') {
        $formkey = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey();
        $formkey = "/form_key/".$formkey."/";        
        $html = preg_replace("/\/form_key\/[a-zA-Z0-9,.-]+\//", $formkey, $html); 
    }  
    return parent::_afterToHtml($html);
}
```

I'm thinking of switching to a full page cache in future but fixing this would be nice as configuring another cache method takes a lot time as well.

So please help if you have a better idea than this dirty quick fix.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have built a better fix.
I fix the whole HTML output at once, and I also fix **form_key** fields in hidden form inputs.

My extension listens to the event `controller_front_send_response_before`. The method is `controllerFrontSendResponseBefore` in `app/code/community/JeroenVermeulen/BlockCache/Model/Observer.php`

https://github.com/jeroenvermeulen/jeroenvermeulen-blockcache/

It is better to use events instead of overrides, because you don't have the risk of 2 extensions overriding the same core functionality. An event is also more likely to work after a Magento upgrade.

Comment: Notice: There is also a dedicated Stack Exchange for Magento:
https://magento.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Hey Jeroen,

I agree that hooking to an event is generally better than overriding classes, but I'm not sure if your solution really is better for this scenario.

In my case I really have to override the class, because of the cache methods I need to override. If another extension will override the same class I will have to merge them ... I'm aware of that.

But at this moment your solution seems to me like taking a sledgehammer to crack a nut. I only had the problem with this block because I'm using caching. Where did you need to replace the form_keys? Really need to edit the whole response?

Comment: Well using events instead of overrides is getting more and more popular, because it prevents clashes between extensions. Because I use the lightweight 'is_a()' statement very early, the block observer is not very heavy. Because I pull the whole content of category and product detail pages out of cache, the form key needs to be replaced in the content, otherwise the 'Add to cart' buttons don't work in Magento > 1.8

Comment: Can you give me a hint what you mean with the 'is_a()' statement? Something like 'instanceof'? Is it a Magento function?

Comment: You are right, it is something like `instanceof`. [More info: PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-a.php). I [discovered](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20870004/1339585) a few weeks ago `instanceof` is 2x faster, so I switched to using `instanceof` in my extension.