# Check if variable which stores name of a class is an instanceof a class

Tags: php

I might have missed something in [is_a()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-a.php) and [instanceof](http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.opcodes.instanceof.php) but is there a way to make this string version work?

```
$myclass = 'MyClass';

if ($myclass instanceof MyClass) {
    echo 'Yes';
} else {
    echo 'No';
}
```

This works fine as expected and prints **Yes**:

```
$myclass = new MyClass();

if ($myclass instanceof MyClass) {
    echo 'Yes';
 else {
    echo 'No';
}
```

Comment: `$myclass = 'MyClass';

if (class_exists($myclass)) {
    echo 'Yes';
} else {
    echo 'No';
}` perhaps?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3017684/what-is-the-difference-between-is-a-and-instanceof

Link above has good explanation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Question:**
`Check if variable which stores name of a class is an instanceof a class`

**My answer:**

If a variable stores a name of a class it cannot be instance of that class because it's a string!

**What you might wanted:**

`Check if variable stores a name of existing class`

**Solution to that:**

```
if (class_exists($myclass)) { ... }
```