# Why does using instanceof calls take so much time?

Tags: php

I don't know why `instanceof` calls take so much time. For example:

```
if($this instanceof Player){
    // Lags the server.
}
```

but if I add this in the player class:

```
public function isPlayer(){
    return true;
}
```

And then do:

```
if($this->isPlayer()){
    //Super fast.
}
```

It is much faster. So, when I do `if ($this instanceof Player)` what is the server really doing during that time?

Comment: Actually it's faster than `is_a` function. Look at this interesting question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3017684/what-is-the-difference-between-is-a-and-instanceof

Comment: how deeply nested is your inheritance chain? e.g. if `$this` is a 20th generation extension of player, it'll take a while to iterate back up the chain v.s. if it was a direct `$this extends Player` single-generation

Comment: Interesting, but I'm not an using is_a() method. I simply put a function in all entity classes isPlayer() and make it return a value if it is true or false, then using this function I can avoid a instanceof operator.

Comment: Note that calling `$this->isPlayer()` will throw an error if `$this` is _not_ an instance of `Player` (and assuming that whatever is _is_ does not have an `isPlayer()` function defined).

Comment: @MarcB It actually varies depending on how many people join the server, so usually it would be about 50-100 generations.

Comment: @partick Yes, you are correct. I made sure to define it in all cases that could be $this.

Comment: you have objects inheriting 50-100 deep? that's ludicrous. `a extends b extends c .... extends 50th_ancestor`? Exactly what the heck are you doing that requires this many ancestors?

Comment: Opps! I mis-read that. No, I have 2 generations extending it,

Comment: How long exactly is "much time"? Have you benchmarked it? Do you have any hard numbers?

Comment: instanceof should not lag the server in a 2 generation inheritance, in my optinion there is another reason

Answer (score 1):

PHP uses string comparison for instanceof checks.

If you have very long classnames or calling it very often there can be a significant slowdown. Please have a look at the Instanceof section at https://phpgoodness.wordpress.com/2010/07/23/some-php-performance-myths/, there is a performance comparison which shows the difference.