# PHP - a product of a factory has special method

Tags: php, factory-pattern

I try to use factory pattern to create products. I create a interface for product classes to implement and design a factory which will generate product according to the parameters pass to it.

*Interface*

```
interface Product
{
  public function getName();
}
```

*Products*

```
class ProductA implements Product{
  public function getName()
  {
    return 'A'; 
  }
}

class ProductB implements Product{
  public function getName()
  {
    return 'B'; 
  }
  public function SpecialMethod()
  {
    return 'only B';
  }
}
```

*Factory*

```
class Factory(){
  public function getProduct($type)
  {
    switch ($type) {
      case 'A':
        return new ProductA();
        break;

      case 'B':
        return new ProductA();
        break;

      default:
        # code...
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

*Usage*

```
function someBussinessLogic($type)
{

  // ...ignore...

  $factory = new Factory;
  $product = $factory->getProduct($type);

  if ($type == 'B') {
    $product->SpecialMethod();
  }

  // ...ignore...
}
```

In the usage, I have to check if `$type` is 'B'. I think this behavior is kind of weird. Should I just do this or put `SpecialMethod` to `interface Product`? Or there is any better way?

---

[edit]

Yes, I'm worried about there will be Product C, D, E... in the future and each has its own special method. If I just put all special method to the interface, the interface will become very huge and all other products will need to implement meaningless methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do this

```
$product = $factory->getProduct($type);

if (is_a($product, ProductB::class)) {
   $product->SpecialMethod();
}
```

Or use an interface if you will have many classes with `SpecialMethod`, then you can check for the interface instead of a single class.

For reference [is_a](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-a.php)

> Checks if the given object is of this class or has this class as one of its parents.

You can also use [instanceOf](http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.opcodes.instanceof.php)

```
if ($product instanceof ProductB::class) {
   $product->SpecialMethod();
}
```

Here is a helpful post on the difference between the two

[What is the difference between is_a and instanceof?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3017684/what-is-the-difference-between-is-a-and-instanceof)

**Also**

I don't see anything inherently wrong with this, either

```
interface ProductInterface
{
    public function getName();
    public function SpecialMethod();
}
```

However I would also add an Abstract class into it.

```
abstract class AbstractProduct impliments ProductInterface{
    abstract public function getName();
    public function SpecialMethod()
    {
        return ''; //or false
    }
}

class ProductA extends AbstractProduct {
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'A'; 
    }
}

class ProductB extends AbstractProduct {
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'A'; 
    }
    //override the concrete method in abstract class
    public function SpecialMethod()
    {
        return 'only B'; 
    }
}
```

This way you can just leave that method empty in the other classes, as long as you are not relying on `SpecialMethod` for some type of return value. I would also modify the name like I have, but that's just my preference.

Then you can do this

```
$product = $factory->getProduct($type);
$product->SpecialMethod();  //return "only B" or ""
```

Because most the classes will inherent the empty method from the abstract class, and only those products that implement their override will make a difference.  This makes sense if multiple product would have that method, but it also makes sense to make a separate interface and check for that.  So it more depends on the specifics of what `SpecialMethod` actually does.

Answer (score 0):

I would say it depends. If you are planning to add this method to more classes over time, go for the interface. I wouldnt consider it bad practise if there would be some classes, which still have to implement this method but having an empty body. This way you could get rid of your if and dont have to go back to your code, if class `C` will implement this method too.

If it will ONLY be this one special case, I (personally) would  go for the if like you already have.

---

Or maybe you can call the special method where you call `someBusinessLogic()` since nothing follows it after this statement. With that I mean something like:

```
someBusinessLogic($type)->specialMethod();
```

If this approach is working for your existing code, I would highly suggest to go this way instead of the if.

Answer (score 0):

**Factory Pattern:** Acc. to Wikipedia, the factory method pattern is a creational pattern that uses factory methods to deal with the problem of creating objects without having to specify the exact class of the object that will be created.
Here the problem you mentioned is with the check before calling  *$product->SpecialMethod();*
If we go through the class implementations it is clear that *ProductB* only needs *specialMethod*. So in the *someBussinessLogic($type)*, regardless of how the code design is, practically you only want to call the *specialMethod* in case of *typeB*, as there is no *specialMethod* functionality in other cases (as in why you would want to call *specialMethod* in all the cases?). So you automatically need a check. 
 On the other hand, if you are writing a generic code, your entities should not have specific behaviors. And if they have, you should plug them out of the generic code, rather than putting a check inside the generic code.

Now, as you will have to handle such checks explicitly then, you may wonder how the factory pattern is helping you?. Well, factory pattern gonna shine the moment you want to change the functionalities of a particular type, you will have a single point from where you could plug out a class and plug in the updated class with new functionalities.
Bottom line is if you want to handle specific behavior in your generic code, as in the above case, you **will** have to write a check somewhere in your code. Its better be outside of the generic modules, rather than compromising the integrity of the generic code.